# Do you know any online form instead of Google forms and Survey monkey?

Tags: gratis, google-apps

Even though Google forms can do skip logic, its feature is poor. Meanwhile, Survey monkey can do it, though, it is not free.

What I need is having skip logic feature and free one. The way of operation is easier. Can you recommend me any suitable online form

Comment: i don't use it myself, but [LimeSurvey](https://www.limesurvey.org/) fits your (short) bill.

Comment: Thank you for your kind information.

I roughly checked Japanese version.They would not accept any inquiry from the personnel. My status is a freelancer.

I am asking you whether English version accepts any inquiry from the personnel.For a short while, I need assistance.
If they will not accept it, I will appreciate if you introduce me another one.

Comment: i'm not sure what you are talking about... please explain it to me, or better expand your OP with more concrete requirements.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy it looks like he is looking for free support. Also Omaruko2016, I think this could be tagged with [gratis] if you are looking for free (price=0).

Comment: Did you try https://alternativeto.net/software/google-forms/